RANDBETWEEN but only when TRUE
I need a way to use the RAND function; RANDBETWEEN in this case; and prevent it from recalculating without turning off automatic calculations for the entire sheet.
The Setup is based around this one function currently:
`=IF(A2=TRUE,RANDBETWEEN(B2,C2),"")`

[Example Table] (https://i.sstatic.net/65YpFjeB.png)
What I need is for the end point users to be able to turn cells to TRUE, as many as they choose to; without one causing RAND to recalculate any that are already TRUE; and then to SUM those results as they are generated.
So User 1 might make A2 and A3 TRUE, then User 2 might make A4 and A5 TRUE, I need to preserve User 1's results, and sum them as they are with user 2's results.
I've tried turning off automatic calculations, but it breaks too many functions on the rest of the sheet; unless there's a way to set manual calculation only for this range? but I've not been able to find a feature like that.
I've tried a few variations on using colour to just obfuscate the result and then reveal without re-rcalculating; but revealing it with a checkbox true/false still causes it to recalculate anyway.
I've looked a creating my own random number generator type thing; but I think that's quite a bit beyond my skills as they are.
I tried RAND-ing the result in a different cell then return that result only when true; hoping to find a way of keeping the last figure in the cell until the checkbox is made FALSE then TRUE again to replace it with the new figure but I couldn't find a way of retaining the value in the cell without creating a circular reference that re-calculated itself on turning false anyway.
I've only Tagged Excel because I tried asking before and was told to edit it but I couldn't edit the original post? so I've posted again; but to be clear, I'd like to find a solution that's applicable to G-Sheets as well, or vice versa if there's a way to do it on G-sheets that won't work on Excel; I'll happily recreate the entire rest of the actual sheet on whichever platform has a solution for this.
Update: Solution!
At least, the one that solves it enough for me (coming at this with zero VBA experience) to use moving forwards!
Replace Checkbox with button that calls a macro to execute the RANDBETWEEN Function and print to each result cell.
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call PrintResult
End Sub

Sub PrintResult()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change "Sheet1" to 
your sheet name
            ws.Range("D2").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(ws.Range("B2").Value, ws.Range("C2").Value)
    End Sub

Thanks for the Tips! @GSerg

possible duplicate of How to keep random numbers from changing in Excel?

possible duplicate of How can I prevent changes to formula results after first use?

@GSerg Appreciate the similarities but I need a different solution for this case; as mentioned in my question, turning off automatic calculations breaks the rest of the sheet that the result of this table feeds into.

Have you considered the other options given? It sounds like https://superuser.com/a/905237/52365 is the right solution for you.

@GSerg Thank you for sharing the Passwords one, that's a little closer to my issue; but there isn't a solution there that would be suitable for this; I'm looking for a solution other than "just paste the values over the formula, then put the formula back in manually" which is all those ones have really.

It's the opposite of that, isn't it. You get VBA to put the formula in and replace it with a value. You link that VBA code to the event of the clicking that tickbox.

@GSerg Okay, I will try this:
Sub ertdfgcvb(Target As Range)
For Each Cell In Target
Cell.Formula = "=IF(A2=TRUE,RANDBETWEEN(B2,C2),"")"
Cell.Value2 = Cell.Value2
Next
End Sub

@GSerg Okay, I have it in there; how do I link that VBA code to the event of the clicking that tickbox? This is all new to me.

That depends on which tickbox you used? If it's a Forms one, link it to a cell and handle Worksheet_Change on that sheet to run that code when a respective cell changes. If it's an ActiveX one, handle the _Click event on the checkbox directly.

I agree you will have to use VBA for this. Because excel calculates the whole sheet by design. There is just no way to keep some cells unchanged while re calculating other cells.

@rachel Thank you, I've never had to resort to VBA before so this is going to be a learning process for me.

Update: Solution!
At least, the one that solves it enough for me (coming at this with zero VBA experience) to use moving forwards!
Replace Checkbox with button that calls a macro to execute the RANDBETWEEN Function and print to each result cell.
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call PrintResult
End Sub

Sub PrintResult()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change "Sheet1" to 
your sheet name
            ws.Range("D2").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(ws.Range("B2").Value, ws.Range("C2").Value)
    End Sub

Thanks for the Tips! @GSerg
